# Include produces null in use case with DTO class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a linq statement that seems to be working fine and getting correct data:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
      List<DiaryRecord> diaryRecords = await this.Context.DiaryRecords
                                                 .Include(d => d.Project)                                                              
                                                 .Include(e => e.Employees)                                                                  
                                                 .ToListAsync();
      return Ok(diaryRecords);
    }
```

Employees is

```
public virtual ICollection<Personell> Employees { get; set; }
```

I am requesting this list in Client assembly by:

```
this.DiaryRecords = await this.HttpClient
    .GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<DiaryRecordModelDTO>>("api/Diary");
```

Where employees is:

```
public ICollection<PersonellDTO> Employees { get; set; }
```

As an output `this.DiaryRecords` has all the needed information, except that Employees is null here. Is an error coming because of different classes `PersonellDTO` and `Personell`. How to make it work?

Comment: If `Diaryrecords` is well formatted and populated, when it leaves the controller and is being sent down the wire, the problem must be located at the client parsing the json. Try reading the body as a string and see, if employees is being received correctly using `await ....Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` My gut tells me, that the compiler can't parse `Employees` to `PersonellDTO`, but without the object definition, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Marco I think so too, that as there are different classes/models PersonellDTO and Personell, mapping is failing. Is there any way to map them? BTW I am not using Automapper, doing all manually so far if it's needed.

Comment: Don't delete it. Post it as an answer, as trivial as it sounds. Theres the odd chance, somebody will get some help out of it.

Comment: @HiFo You have to post  both Personel  and both DiaryRecord classes to see the difference. Why we should guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.GetFromJsonAsync is always very tricky and never use interface to deserialize json. And json does not know what classe were used PersonellDTO or Personell to create http response.

in your DTO interface this should be fixed to a concrete class

```
public List<PersonellDTO> Employees { get; set; }
```

And I always use code like this for httpclient

```
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DiaryRecordModelDTO>(stringData);
    }
```